# How to override js function in odoo

Tags: javascript, jquery, inheritance, web, odoo

I want to load /shop/checkout url.
function is :

```
odoo.define('change_info_order.website_sale_change_info_order', function (require) {
    "use strict";

    $('.oe_website_sale').each(function () {
        var oe_website_sale = this;

        $(oe_website_sale).on('click', 'a.js_checkout_btn', function (ev) {
            var e = document.getElementById("js_customer_change");
            // var customer_id = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
            var customer_id = **e.value**;
            if (customer_id) {
                window.location.href = '/shop/checkout';
            }
            else {
                Dialog.alert(self, _t("Please select the customer"));
            };
        });

    });
});
```

My inherit code is:

```
odoo.define('website_sale_product_list.website_sale_change_info_order', function (require) {
    "use strict";

    $('.oe_website_sale').each(function () {
        var oe_website_sale = this;

        $(oe_website_sale).on('click', 'a.js_checkout_btn', function (ev) {
            window.location.href = '/shop/checkout';
        });

    });
});
```

Problem is can't load my inherited javascript file. How to fix this problem? 
I need any solution.
Console:
[image]

the line code is:[image]

/comment:My js file can't load/

Comment: Did you load it into the assets?

Comment: yes, i load it into the assets

Comment: just copy paste and your code!

Comment: Sorry, that's code is my full code.

Comment: I use console log, can't load   $('.oe_website_sale').each(function () {..} this section.

Comment: Have you checked weather your JS file is loaded or not by debug with assets.

Comment: You should activate developer mode in order for you to see exactly where in the many many JavaScript files this error happened in the frontend code. In developer mode the frontend code is unpacked to single JavaScript files in the modules.